# c# service for Shopify Admin API integration rate limit issue

Tags: c#, .net, shopify

I build a Shopify integration over 3 months ago and I can't seem to finish how to manage the rate limit.
I used a simple Task.WaitAll with a list of tasks sent to Shopify and had a limit of request at the time but I still got with 429 rate limit error or task cancellation error.
Now I'm using TokenBucket nugget package and I am getting task cancellation error all the time and nothing seems to sync.
Honestly, I'm very frustrated and about to throw the project out the window unless maybe someone can give me a hint how I can fix this.
Tnx in advanced...

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at your C# responses from Shopify, particularly, the headers. Every header Shopify sends you has rate limit information. Before they send you a dreaded 429 error, they are showing you how many requests you can make before you run out. So if you are able to examine your headers, that is where you can put some logic in to deal with rate limits. Since Shopify adds to your limit when you stop making calls, when your limit approaches zero, you can simply rest a bit, wait, sleep, whatever you call it and then start back up with new limits.

I am sure C# has a simple hack for this already built in to the code used to make HTTPS calls. It is not like rate limiting is new, rare or unique to Shopify, it is used everywhere. In fact, there are probably C# hacks for Shopify that do what you need. Have you tried looking for any?

Comment: I have not, I will look into the heading. Tnx for the hint.